# PSQL does not detect .pgpass file

Tags: postgresql

I have tried

1. Setting the permission of .pgpass to 0600
2. Confirmed .pgpass is in my user's home directory (/home/brandon/.pgpass)
3. use -w in pg_dumpall command
4. Confirmed the data in .pgpass is correct

The script (https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Automated_Backup_on_Linux)  for automated backup works if I type the password again and again which is why i added -w to all the commands. It for some reason does not read the .pgpass file .

There are multiple error messages but they are generally this.

```
 pg_dumpall: could not connect to database "template1": FATAL:  password    authentication failed for user "postgres"
```

FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"

pg_pass file :

```
localhost:5432:my_db:postgres:password
```

command line :

```
username@droplet:~/ProjectDir$ bash cronjob/db_backup/pg_backup.sh
Making backup directory in /home/backups/database/postgresql/2017-12-06/


Performing globals backup
--------------------------------------------

Globals backup
cronjob/db_backup/pg_backup.sh: line 80: /home/backups/database/postgresql/2017-12-06/globals.sql.gz.in_progress: Permission denied
pg_dumpall: could not connect to database "template1": fe_sendauth: no      password supplied

[!!ERROR!!] Failed to produce globals backup


Performing schema-only backups
--------------------------------------------

psql: fe_sendauth: no password supplied
The following databases were matched for schema-only backup:




Performing full backups
--------------------------------------------

psql: fe_sendauth: no password supplied

All database backups complete!
```

Comment: Look at the PostgreSQL server log. Show your .pgpass file (excluding passwords) and your command line.

Comment: I added the pgpass and commandline output, going to figure out how to find the server log

Answer (score 3):

You should supply the actual calls to `pg_dump` and `pg_dumpall` for a more detailed answer.

However, from your output I see that `pg_dumpall` (?) tries to connect to database `template1`, but in your `.pgpass` file the only database is `my_db`.

You'll have to add entries to `.pgpass` for all databases to which you are trying to connect.

```
localhost:5432:mydb1:postgres:password
localhost:5432:mydb2:postgres:password
localhost:5432:mydb3:postgres:password
```

Alternatively, you are also able to put an `*` as a placeholder for different database names.

```
localhost:5432:*:postgres:password
```

Make sure that all the fields in `.pgpass` are the right/matching ones. If any of them (host, port, etc.) don't match, the unclear, uninformative and arguably wrong `fe_sendauth: no password supplied` error message will be the same.

Comment: I did supplied the calls to pg_dump and pg_dumpall. the script I linked is that with the exception of adding -w to all calls.

Comment: You have to add a line to `.pgpass` for every database to which you want to connect.

Comment: Understood. I will try it tommorow. 12 AM here